# How to quickly change multiple colors in the same text area?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, text, illustrator-scripting

As shown in the following image, how can I change the color of "Ms" or "Mr" in one go?

Is there any existing function that can be used or is it possible to script?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Use "Recolor Artwork"

With the text area selected, click on the *"Recolor Artwork"* button (or go to *Edit → Edit Colors → Reclor Artwork*):

[image]

Under *"Current Colors"* is a list of all the colors present in the selected artwork. The *"New"* column is where you set the colors to change to. You can also combine or swap colors:

[image]

Clicking the new color box will bring up the color picker. Choose your new color:

[image]

You can also change colors by altering Hue/Saturation/Brightness etc. or visually on a color wheel by switching to the 'Edit' tab.

Click OK once you are happy with your changes.

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure Illustrator has these capabilities. There are three ways to "hack" this though.
One would be to assign different character styles to "Mr." and "Ms." and then just edit the global style. 
Another would be to have the "Mr." and "Ms." as separate text objects. 
And the fastest way, that unfortunately removes the possibility of editing, would be to convert all text to outlines, and then just select the words you want to re-colour. Use "Direct Selection Tool" (A) for this. Also, you can copy the text beforehand, and remove the names after you converted them to outlines, changed the title colour, then paste the previous editable names.

Let me know if any of this works for you.

If you would've worked in inDesign, you could've just use the "Find and Replace" function, as it is quite powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to save the colours to use on the text (but can be used on any kind of artwork, not just text) in the swatches panel and set it to global. In this way you can modify the colours on your text just by changing the saved swatches.

- Tick this box to save your colours as global

[image: Save colours as global]

If you already have saved your colours as swatches but forgot to make them global you can still change them by:

- Double clicking on the swatch you wish to change to global
- Select the global option

[image: change colours to global]